# Что происходит в методе convert() класса ColorSchema?

Tags: java, изображения, цвета

Всем привет!

```
public class ColorSchema implements TextColorSchema {

    private char[] arr = {'#', '$', '@', '%', '*', '+', '-', '\''};

    @Override
    public char convert(int color) {
        final int count = 256 / arr.length;
        return arr[(color / count)];
     }
}
```

Логика такова, что программе передают изображение: если интенсивность белого цвета ближе к 0, то выбирается символ `arr[0]`, если ближе к 255 - то `arr[length]`.

Я плохо разбираюсь в передаче изображений в программу, поэтому хочу разобраться: что за `count` получает автор, как и что тут происходит?

256 — это количество символов ASCII. Почему оно делится на длину текущего массива? Что за цифры передаются в `color`?

Что можете посоветовать почитать по этому поводу, не слишком углубляясь в эту тему?

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае 256 не связано с количеством символов ASCII, а относится скорее к количеству градаций цвета в упомянутом диапазоне `[0, 255]`.

То есть метод `convert` принимает значение цвета `color` из данного диапазона.

Переменная `count` определяет длину поддиапазона, который приходится на один символ, отвечающий за цвет.  В данном случае это значение составит 256 / 8 = 32.  В конце вычисляется символ, соответствующий цвету:

- `color ∊ [  0,  31] -> arr[0] -> '#'` - чёрный
- `color ∊ [ 32,  63] -> arr[1] -> '$'`
  ...
- `color ∊ [224, 255] -> arr[7] -> '\''` - белый

Если `color` выйдет за пределы диапазона `[0, 255]`, произойдёт выход за пределы массива и будет выброшено соответствущее исключение.

Следует заметить, что и переменную `count` и массив символов `arr` можно было определить как константы на уровне класса.

```java
public class ColorSchema implements TextColorSchema {
    private static final char[] COLORS = {'#', '$', '@', '%', '*', '+', '-', '\''};
    private static final int COLOR_COUNT = 256 / COLORS.length;

    @Override
    public char convert(int color) {
        return COLORS[color / COLOR_COUNT];
    }
}
```